# Geometry nodes curve constant offset

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am using *Geometry* nodes - from a given 2D input curve.
How can I produce a new curve with a fixed offset (relative to the original curve)?

I'm trying this node setup:

[image]

... but result is not constant (left), I'm looking for the result seen in the right screen.

[image]

### Edit

I tried quellenform's node tree, but it doesn't work for my curve ...

[image]

The result is a non constant offset:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the updated node setup in the question shows the solution you suggested but for some reason I don't get the same result as you... Your curve is constant offset, mine is not constant... Is there something wrong with my node setup?

Comment: OK I see your updated comment below... "resample curve" fixed it and it's working perfectly... thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be solved like this:

[image]

Use the node `Normal` as input. This node returns the normals of the individual points.

These vectors can then be scaled with the (*Vector Math*) node `Scale` according to the desired distance.

With the node `Set Position` you can finally offset the individual points to a new position.

---

If this does not work well (What can sometimes be the case with Bezier curves), or the curve has idiosyncratic normals, then use the node `Resample Curve` beforehand, this would smooth the curve.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the normal already be normalized ? ><

Comment: @Gorgious ...Shame on me, you are of course absolutely right :D

Comment: wow that was the fastest edit I've ever seen ! Cheers :)

Comment: This looks like a really good answer. I'm unable to recreate the same result. It looks like you are using blender 3.1.2 - I'm using blender 3.2 but that shouldn't make a difference. I recreated the node diagram using Set Position, Scale, and Normal but the offset is not constant in my result. Did you do anything special to your input curve? I updated the original question node diagram and result to show what I have now.

Comment: This solution address the correction exactly: "relative to the original curve". But as an alternative solution is there any way to make the second curve offset a fixed value rather than a scale percentage?

Comment: @stackzz No, it makes no difference if you use version 3.1.2 or 3.2, ...give me a few minutes, the solution is very simple.

Comment: @stackzz btw: The scaling of the vector is not a percentage, even if the node is called "Scale", but always absolute. Since you are scaling a normalized vector here, the length always corresponds exactly to the value you specified for the scaling, so it is always "fixed", because, for example, 1*1=1.

Comment: @quellenform - you are a genius!